# How to use user custom field value in custom object field in filter in Reports?

Tags: reporting, filters, user-record

I am Trying to create a report on Object__c, I have custom field(projectName__c) value on the current user. So while creating the reports, I am planning to filter like below:.

Object__c.projectName__c=currentUser.projectName__c;

How to achieve this?

If you provide the solution, That will be Very glad.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula field in the custom object which is checkbox type and formula will be
IF(projectName__c=user.projectName__c,true,false)

And create a report where apply filter forumulaField__c = true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that you may refer. You have the solution. Please mark answer if it helps.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gp92AAA